# Confused about use of List and Array

Tags: c#, xml, class, datagridview

I'm going to have to break these down into two datagridviews later, but I'm skeptical about Inquiry class holding array of lineitems as I have in the code below. I'm not sure if it's even the proper way to do it.

I plan to later place these objects into XML file and wire that up too as datasource also to the same datagridviews.

Here is the interface I'm preparing for this [image]

```
   List<Inquiry> myInquiries = new List<Inquiry>();

    class Inquiry
    {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string company { get; set; }
        public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string faxNumber { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public LineItem[] lineitems { get; set; }
    }

    class LineItem
    {
        public int quantity { get; set; }
        public string partNumber { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if array of lineitems inside inquiry class is going to cause me problems, since I plan to wire list of inquiries to datagridviews.

Answer (score 0):

You will be wanting to use a DataTable to map values to a DataGridView. If you don't your column names will be your property names. If you use a DataTable, you can specify custom column names.

As for using an array or a List. Lists are easier to use because you can apply linq or use any of the interfaces that it implements. I am not saying that arrays are bad, its just that Lists are better.